# Getting shared data with photo and text

Tags: android, share, intentfilter, android-sharing, data-sharing

I would like to share data into my app the same in WhatsApp:
[image]

When I'm trying it in my own app I only get the text ("Check out...").
How can I get the rest of the data: Image, Title, Description and website address?

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String action = intent.getAction();
 String type = intent.getType();
 if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        } else if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendImage(intent); // Handle single image being sent
        }
 } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if (type.startsWith("image/")) {
            handleSendMultipleImages(intent);
        }
 }
```

I only get ACTION_SEND with EXTRA_TEXT.

Comment: That image is appended from the link which you have shared.

Comment: @KirankumarZinzuvadia So I can sample the link in the back-end and create this manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can stream image with intent to share image. But mostly it depends on application which you select to share supports image stream sharing or not.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpg");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share image using"));
```

Check this link to get idea about sharing options.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Sharing-Content-with-Intents

And to receive shared data from other app check this link :

https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Comment: Thanks but I want to get the data from a different app not to send it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it at the end is to parse the link meta data tags in the backend and send the details to the app.